# Is there a Geiger counter sound in Fallout Tactics?

Tags: fallout-tactics

Just curious as I've been re-playing this old classic Fallout Game.  I noticed that levels with "green radiation" don't seem to show a geiger counter, or any sort of notification of 'being radiated'.

I only see "Radiated" after the fact of a character receiving a high dose. Maybe I'm just recalling Fallout 3's system.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sound indeed. In Fallout Tactics, the only way to know you're radiated is in your characters panel. And as far as I remember, you can't even now the levels because there is no geiger counter in the game (unlike F1 and F2).

So basically, the best practice is to keep an eye on it, and heal yourself when you're infected, using RadAway. I know you can become addicted to RadAway in F1 and F2, but I'm not sure when it comes to FT. Try to limit your use of it, just in case.

Answer (score -2):

Yep, the mechanic for the originals is basically 'you'll know when it happens' until you have a [Geiger Counter](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Geiger_counter).

Locations are as follows:

Fallout 1 - "One can be purchased in the Cathedral from the shopkeeper. Another can be found in the General Store in The Hub and an additional two bought from Jake in Old Town and Killian in Junktown."

Fallout 2 - "One can be found in Vault City, in the lockers on the 3rd floor of Vault 8. There is also a Geiger counter in an easy to lockpick locker in the greeting office at the entrance of the city. The door is locked, so a lockpick is needed to access it. There is also a variety of valuable loot there, too. Another can be found on a bench in the basement of New Reno Arms."

Comment: Umm.. I'm referring to Fallout Tactics, I don't care about F1 or F2... thanks anyway

Comment: Whoops, didn't see the tag. A lot of similar mechanics in Tactics though. There's a visual of the Geiger Counter in the wiki for tactics too, but no information on where to find them. Having one though will probably be the only way to get an actual readout. I don't remember there being any indicator sounds for them.